# Hittesting against a level building array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sprite, hittest

I'm building a top down (birds eye view) game in flash, a fairly simple concept, a la early Legend of Zelda or Final Fantasy games. I have the level built and the character added and moveable, with a scrolling camera, yet one problem vexes me. Hittesting.

The level is created using an array- a simple [1,1,1]; array, where it checks to see if a value in the array matches, then creates a simple square Sprite and adds it to a larger Sprite that holds every item. Finally, the player is then added to the stage and can be controlled using the arrow keys. I'm using this as a movement system:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function checkDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
   switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 65 :
        leftDown = true;
        break;
    case 37 :
        leftDown = true;
        break;
    case 68 :
        rightDown = true;
        break;
    case 39 :
        rightDown = true;
        break;
    case 87 :
        upDown = true;
        break;
    case 38 :
        upDown = true;
        break;
    case 83 :
        downDown = true;
        break;
    case 40 :
        downDown = true;
        break;
}
}

function checkUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 65 :
        leftDown = false;
        break;
    case 37 :
        leftDown = false;
        break;
    case 68 :
        rightDown = false;
        break;
    case 39 :
        rightDown = false;
        break;
    case 87 :
        upDown = false;
        break;
    case 38 :
        upDown = false;
        break;
    case 83 :
        downDown = false;
        break;
    case 40 :
        downDown = false;
        break;
}
}

function update(e:Event):void {
if (upDown) {
    if (genericHolder.y >= boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 4]) {
        genericHolder.y = boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 4];
        Player.y-=power;
    }
    if (genericHolder.y < boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 4]) {
        genericHolder.y+=power;
    }
    Player.Stand.visible = false;
    Player.Forwards.visible = false;
    Player.Rights.visible = false;
    Player.Lefts.visible = false;
    Player.Backwards.visible = true;
    playerDirection = 2;
}
if (downDown) {
    if (genericHolder.y <= boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 3]) {
        genericHolder.y = boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 3];
        Player.y+= power;
    }
    if (genericHolder.y > boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 3]) {
        genericHolder.y-=power;
    }
    Player.Stand.visible = false;
    Player.Backwards.visible = false;
    Player.Rights.visible = false;
    Player.Lefts.visible = false;
    Player.Forwards.visible = true;
    playerDirection = 1;
}
if (leftDown) {
    if (genericHolder.x >= boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 2]) {
        genericHolder.x = boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 2];
        Player.x -= power;
    }
    if (genericHolder.x < boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 2]) {
        genericHolder.x+=power;
    }
    Player.Stand.visible = false;
    Player.Backwards.visible = false;
    Player.Forwards.visible = false;
    Player.Rights.visible = false;
    Player.Lefts.visible = true;
    playerDirection = 4;
}
if (rightDown) {
    if (genericHolder.x <= boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 1]) {
        genericHolder.x = boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 1];
        Player.x += power;
    }
    if (genericHolder.x > boundariesLevelOne[(room*4) - 1]) {
        genericHolder.x-=power;
    }
    Player.Stand.visible = false;
    Player.Backwards.visible = false;
    Player.Forwards.visible = false;
    Player.Lefts.visible = false;
    Player.Rights.visible = true;
    playerDirection = 3;
}
if (!upDown && !downDown && !leftDown && !rightDown) {
    Player.Backwards.visible = false;
    Player.Forwards.visible = false;
    Player.Rights.visible = false;
    Player.Lefts.visible = false;
    Player.Stand.visible = true;
    Player.Stand.gotoAndStop(playerDirection);
}
if (Player.Stand) {
    Player.Stand.gotoAndStop(playerDirection);
     }
}
```

TL;DR The background moves instead of the player, and movement is controlled by variables.

How can I Hittest against any of the sprites that I've added? At the moment, if I try to Hittest a specific Sprite, it tests agains the entire Sprite holder, not the specific Sprite I want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the hittest method?

http://www.actionscriptmoron.com/AS3Tutorials/hittest-hittestobject/

What do you mean it tests again the entire sprite holder just get the reference of the contained object and pass it to the hittest method. it should work.

Comment: It doesn't hitTest against single objects in the sprite holder, just against the entire thing.

Comment: I cannt see any hit testig in your code sample above can you please update with your attempt to perform hit test to the singe objects